# Error with single quotes inside text in select statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Getting the error using Postgresql 9.3:

```
select 'hjhjjjhjh'mnmnmnm'mn'
```

Error:

> ERRO:syntax error in or next to "'mn'"
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 26

I tried replace single quote inside text with:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('hjhjjjhjh'mnmnmnm'mn', '\\''+', '''', 'g')
```

and

```
select '$$hjhjjjhjh'mnmnmnm'mn$$'
```

but it did not work.

Below is the real code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_mallet_input2() RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
DECLARE 
sch name;
r record;   
BEGIN

    FOR sch IN 
     select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name not in ('test','summary','public','pg_toast','pg_temp_1','pg_toast_temp_1','pg_catalog','information_schema') 
    LOOP 

         FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT rp.id as id,g.classified as classif, concat(rp.summary,rp.description,string_agg(c.message, ''. '')) as mess
            FROM ' || sch || '.report rp
            INNER JOIN ' || sch || '.report_comment rc ON rp.id=rc.report_id
            INNER JOIN ' || sch || '.comment c ON rc.comments_generatedid=c.generatedid 
            INNER JOIN ' || sch || '.gold_set g ON rp.id=g.key
            WHERE g.classified = any (values(''BUG''),(''IMPROVEMENT''),(''REFACTORING''))
            GROUP BY g.classified,rp.summary,rp.description,rp.id'
         LOOP

            IF r.classif = 'BUG' THEN
                EXECUTE format('Copy( select REPLACE(''%s'', '''', '''''''') as m ) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/BUG/'|| quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id::text || '.txt ''',r.mess);
            ELSIF r.classif = 'IMPROVEMENT' THEN
                EXECUTE format('Copy( select REPLACE(''%s'', '''', '''''''') as m ) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/IMPROVEMENT/'|| quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id || '.txt '' ',r.mess);
            ELSIF r.classif = 'REFACTORING' THEN
                EXECUTE format('Copy( select REPLACE(''%s'', '''', '''''''') as m ) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/REFACTORING/'|| quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id || '.txt '' ',r.mess);
            END IF;             

         END LOOP;



    END LOOP; 
    RETURN; 

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT; 

select * FROM generate_mallet_input2();
```

Error:

> ERRO:  erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "mailto"
>   LINHA 1: ...e.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$<strike>HTTPCLIENT-803</strike>).
> The new SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket method calls the X509HostnameVerifier with InetSocketAddress.getHostName() parameter. When the selected IP address has a reverse lookup name, the verifier is called with the resolved name, and so the IP check fails.
> 4.0 release checked for original ip/hostname, but this cannot be done with the new connectSocket() method. 
> The TestHostnameVerifier.java only checks 127.0.0.1/.2 and so masked the issue, because the matching certificate has both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1", but actually only "localhost" is matched. A test case with 8.8.8.8 would be better.I committed a slightly better workaround for the problem that does not require reverse DNS lookups.
> Oleg. I had to resort to a fairly ugly hack in order to fix the problem. A better solution would require changes to the X509HostnameVerifier API. I felt that deprecation of the X509HostnameVerifier interface was not warranted, as the use of an IP address for CN in a certificate was a hack by itself.
> Please review.
> Oleg . Even the second one requires the server presenting a trusted certificate. I don't see much difference beetween the two cases.. Wrong test. Try to connect to https://93.62.162.60:8443/. The certificate has CN=93.62.162.60, but the check is done for 93-62-162-60.ip23.fastwebnet.it. Hmm, my comment was not meant to revert the patch. The first scenario was already exploitable and still is. Your patch is the "correct" solution without breaking the API.
> But to avoid any security issue (including the ones already present) the API have to be changed.. I am not able to reproduce the problem. SSL connections to remote peers pass the default host name verification.
> ---
> executing requestGET https://www.verisign.com/ HTTP/1.1
> [DEBUG] SingleClientConnManager - Get connection for route HttpRoute[{s}->https://www.verisign.com]
> [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to [www.verisign.com/69.58.181.89:443](http://www.verisign.com/69.58.181.89:443)
> [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
> [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
> [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: GET / HTTP/1.1
> [DEBUG] headers - >> GET / HTTP/1.1
> [DEBUG] headers - >> Host: [www.verisign.com](http://www.verisign.com)
> [DEBUG] headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
> [DEBUG] headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)
> [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> [DEBUG] headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> [DEBUG] headers - << Date: Thu, 03 Feb 2011 20:14:35 GMT
> [DEBUG] headers - << Server: Apache
> [DEBUG] headers - << Set-Cookie: v1st=D732270AE4FC9F76; path=/; expires=Wed, 19 Feb 2020 14:28:00 GMT; domain=.verisign.com
> [DEBUG] headers - << Set-Cookie: v1st=D732270AE4FC9F76; path=/; expires=Wed, 19 Feb 2020 14:28:00 GMT; domain=.verisign.com
> [DEBUG] headers - << X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13
> [DEBUG] headers - << Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
> [DEBUG] headers - << Connection: Keep-Alive
> [DEBUG] headers - << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> [DEBUG] headers - << Content-Type: text/html
> [DEBUG] ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: v1st][value: D732270AE4FC9F76][domain: .verisign.com][path: /][expiry: Wed Feb 19 15:28:00 GMT+01:00 2020]". 
> [DEBUG] ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: v1st][value: D732270AE4FC9F76][domain: .verisign.com][path: /][expiry: Wed Feb 19 15:28:00 GMT+01:00 2020]". 
> [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive for 5000 MILLISECONDS
> ----------------------------------------
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Response content length: -1
> [DEBUG] SingleClientConnManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$ConnAdapter@15ad5c6
> [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Connection shut down
> ---
> Are you using a custom SSL socket factory by any chance? Does it implement the LayeredSchemeSocketFactory interface?
> Oleg. Great work, good patch, thanks!. Well, I looked at the patch. It should fix the issue (though not completely, since the reverse lookup could give a wrong/unresolvable hostname), but as you said it's a crude hack, and this opens to other security issues. Unfortunately the clean fix requires API modification.
> You say using an IP address as CN is a hack, but actually using it as an ipAddress SubjectAlternativeName is perfectly valid.
> The security issues arise from the fact that httpclient tries to match dns generated data (reverse lookups and now also resolved hostnames) instead of what the user actually typed, opening to DNS poisoning or connection redirect attacks.
> First scenario:
> - user wants to connect to 1.2.3.4
> - DNS reverse lookup is xxx.yyy.zzz
> - a malicious proxy redirects the connection to server 4.3.2.1
> - server certificate contains CN or SAN set to xxx.yyy.zzz
> - All OK (but shouldn't)
> Second scenario:
> - user wants to connect to xxx.yyy.zzz
> - hacked DNS incorrectly resolve it to 1.2.3.4
> - server certificate has CN or SAN set to 1.2.3.4
> - The connection is established OK (but clearly shouldn't)
> . Fair enough. I'll revert the patch and close the issue as WONTFIX
> Oleg. The first scenario you are describing would also require involvement of green men from Mars and the malicious 4.3.2.1 server sending a certificate trusted by the client to be practical. 
> Oleg', '', '''') as m ) To '/tmp/csv-temp/BUG/httpclient-HTTPCLIENT-1051.txt '
>   CONTEXTO:  função PL/pgSQL generate_mallet_input2() linha 31 em comando EXECUTE
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "mailto"
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Context: função PL/pgSQL generate_mallet_input2() linha 31 em comando EXECUTE

The retrieved content is a long text on project issues in software repositories and can have html in this text. Html quotes are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the *content* of the string that needs to be escaped, but its *representation* within the SQL you are sending to the server.

In order to *represent* a single `'`, you need to write two in the SQL syntax: `''`. So, `'IMSoP''s answer'` represents the string `IMSoP's answer`, `''''` represents `'`, and `''''''` represents `''`.

But the crucial thing is you need to do this *before* trying to run the SQL. You can't paste an invalid SQL command into a query window and tell it to heal itself.

Automation of the escaping therefore depends entirely how you are creating that SQL. Based on your updated question, we now know that you are creating the SQL statement using pl/pgsql, in this `format()` call:

```
format('Copy( select REPLACE(''%s'', '''', '''''''') as m ) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/BUG/'|| quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id::text || '.txt ''',r.mess)
```

Let's simplify that a bit to make the example clearer:

```
format('select REPLACE(''%s'', '''', '''''''') as m', r.mess)
```

If `r.mess` was `foo`, the result would look like this:

```
select REPLACE('foo', '', ''''') as m
```

This replace won't do anything useful, because the first argument is an empty string, and the second has 3 `'` marks in; but even if you fixed the number of `'` marks, it won't work. If the value of `r.mess` was instead `bad'stuff`, you'd get this:

```
select REPLACE('bad'stuff', '', ''''') as m
```

That's invalid SQL; no matter where you try to run it, it won't work, because Postgres thinks the `'bad'` is a string, and the `stuff` that comes next is invalid syntax.

Think about how it will look if `r.mess` is `SQL injection'); DROP TABLE users --`:

```
select REPLACE('SQL injection'); DROP TABLE users; --', '', ''''') as m
```

Now we've got valid SQL, but it's probably not what you wanted!

So what you need to do is escape the `'` marks in `r.mess` **before** you mix it into the string:

```
format('select '%s' as m', REPLACE(r.mess, '''', ''''''))
```

Now we're changing `bad'stuff` to `bad''stuff` before it goes into the SQL, and ending up with this:

```
select 'bad''stuff' as m
```

This is what we wanted.

There's actually a few better ways to do this, though:

Use the `%L` modifier to [the `format` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT), which outputs an escaped and quoted string literal:

```
format('select %L as m', r.mess)
```

Use the [`quote_literal()` or `quote_nullable()` string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) instead of `replace()`, and concatenate the string together like you do with the filename:

```
'select ' || quote_literal(r.mess) || ' as m'
```

Finally, if the function really looks like it does in your question, you can avoid the whole problem by not using a loop at all; just copy each set of rows into a file using an appropriate `WHERE` clause:

```
 EXECUTE 'Copy
     SELECT concat(rp.summary,rp.description,string_agg(c.message, ''. '')) as mess
        FROM ' || sch || '.report rp
        INNER JOIN ' || sch || '.report_comment rc ON rp.id=rc.report_id
        INNER JOIN ' || sch || '.comment c ON rc.comments_generatedid=c.generatedid 
        INNER JOIN ' || sch || '.gold_set g ON rp.id=g.key
        WHERE g.classified = ''BUG'' -- <-- Note changed WHERE clause
        GROUP BY g.classified,rp.summary,rp.description,rp.id
) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/BUG/'|| quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id::text || '.txt '''
';
```

Repeat for `IMPROVEMENT` and `REFACTORING`. I can't be sure, but in general, acting on a set of rows at once is more efficient than looping over them. Here, you'll have to do 3 queries, but the `= any()` in your original version is probably fairly inefficient anyway.

Comment: I am representing in plpgsql in pgAdmin IDE.  @IMSoP

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a stab at this now that I think I know what you are asking.

You have a field in a table, that when you run `SELECT <field> from <table>` you are returned the result:

```
'This'is'a'test'
```

You want, intead, this result to look like:

```
'This''is''a''test'
```

So:

```
CREATE Table test( testfield varchar(30));
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('''This''is''a''test''');
```

You can run:

```
SELECT 
  '''' || REPLACE(Substring(testfield FROM 2 FOR LENGTH(testfield) - 2),'''', '''''') || '''' 
FROM Test;
```

This will get only the bits inside the first and last single-quote, then it will replace the inner single-quotes with double quotes. Finally it concats back on single-quotes to the beginning and end.

**SQL Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a99e6/4

If it's not double single-quotes that you are looking for in the interior of your string result, then you can change the REPLACE() function to the appropriate character(s). Also, if it's not single-quotes you are looking for to encapsulate the string, then you can change those with the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quoted `'` marks:

```
select 'hjhjjjhjh''mnmnmnm''mn'
```

Comment: How to do this automatic? I need implement on text column from table in the select statement. @Flimzy

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by automatic.

Comment: looks like:  select  REGEXP_REPLACE('hjhjjjhjh'mnmnmnm'mn', '\\''+', '''', 'g'). But it did not work. @Flimzy

Comment: @TarcisioM.: So, as I said, you need to escape your `'` characters.